# How to set environment-specific parameters in Symfony bundle?

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, configuration, mocking

I am writing unit tests for a Symfony2 controller which uses a service to access an external API.  I've made a mock subclass of this service for unit testing purposes, which checks that the controller gives it the right input.

The config for the service is in `{bundle}/Resources/config/parameters.yml`.  At the moment I am overriding the service class parameter in `app/config/config_test.yml` so that my unit tests will use the mock service.

I'd like to put the test config somewhere in my bundle if I can, but when I make a config_test.yml in `{bundle}/Resources/config` that gets ignored.  Is there any way to make this work, or does my environment-specific config have to stay under the app directory?

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest to use your own [loader](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/resources.html) in bundle. And depending on env load different yml file.

Answer (score 0):

For any one that got here looking for a way to set different environments, here is the solution from the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#test).

Essentially, you need to add a `framework` key with a `test` paramater set to `true` or any other **non-false** value:

```yaml
imports:
    - { resource: config_dev.yml }

framework:
    test: ~
    session:
        storage_id: session.storage.filesystem
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question doesn't make sense since you're talking about unit testing and reading some configuration which is oxymoronic in the first place.

If you're really doing a unit test — that is, just testing a single class when all the dependencies are either stubbed or mocked out — then you're not supposed to access any configuration. You just mock the service interface/class with PHPUnit mocks or Mockery, define expectations on that mock in terms of what methods should be called and which arguments should they receive and then just verify that those expectations were met.